# How to query two access database(accdb) files that have different schema?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I need your help.

Suppose there are two access database(accdb) files which have some columns with same names but some are not. For example:
[start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKwmy.png)

Then how to make a query to both database at the same time?

```
OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
Source=..\\DATABASE_A.accdb;");
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
Con.Open();
string query = "Select [JOB],[DATE] From TABLE_A WHERE [NAME] = ?";
command.CommandText = query;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", $someDate);

command.Connection = Conn;
adapter.SelectCommand = command;
adapter.Fill(dt);
Conn.Close();
```

However, how about DATABASE_B.accdb to fill the same DataTable dt but TABLE_B's column has different name?I want to form a datatable like that:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQM4y.png)

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What is the purpose? Why not just fill different data tables and do whatever interpretation or merging of data somewhere else?

Comment: The columns seems to have the SAME name "JOB", so I do not see the problem.

Comment: I wonder if I can query two database with one query string.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you would use a [union query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

In *C#* you could use [LINQ Union](https://www.educba.com/linq-union/).

Comment: Please shoe me how to do that.Thank you.

Comment: I provided two links for you to study. So, go ahead, following your preferences.